# Control BarLegend size

Tags: plotting, version-9, legending

I want to plot a big 2D array of experiment data. I need plot axes and tick labels as well as a bar legend using `BarLegend`:

```
ArrayPlot[
 Array[RandomInteger[100] &, {100, 100}],
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Below],
 ImageSize -> 200,
 PlotLabel -> "Test",
 FrameLabel -> {"Axes", "Dimensions"},
 FrameTicks -> Automatic,
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}
]
```

The output I get is

[image: output of the test script]

I am not happy with the size of the `BarLegend`. I would like to have the `BarLegend` with the width and horizontal offset of the actual plot. It properly scales with the image size, if I don't use the `PlotLabel`, `FrameTicks` and `FrameLabel` but I need all of them.

I would be happy also with the solutions, which does work in general case, but needs adjusting some number by hand. So far I have figured out, that I can change the horizontal offset with `PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMargins -> {{20, 20}, {0, 0}}], Below]`, but this does not make the legend smaller.

As the `BarLegend` does not return `Graphics`, I can not just use `Scale[BarLegend["BlueGreenYellow", LegendMargins -> {{20, 20}, {0, 0}}], 2]` etc.

Side note: For plotting experiment data I use `ArrayPlot` instead of `ListContourPlot` and similar because they get very slow for big arrays. And at least `ListContourPlot` suffers from the same problem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As it often happens, when I was researching for writing a fine question I also digged through [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BarLegend.html) and found the answer. There is an option `LegendMarkerkSize` which in my opinion has an unintuitive name in the case of the `BarLegend`. Anyway it is exactly meant to do what I needed:

```
testPlot = ArrayPlot[
  Array[RandomInteger[100] &, {100, 100}],
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 125, 
     LegendMargins -> {{10, 0}, {0, 0}}], Below],
  ImageSize -> 200,
  PlotLabel -> "Test",
  FrameLabel -> {"Axes", "Dimensions"},
  FrameTicks -> Automatic,
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}
  ]
```

Outcome

[image]

As I already wrote the detailed question, I hope it was worth sharing the solution.