# Size of BarLegend

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

Whenever I try to fit the sizes of the plot and the `BarLegend`, it's a struggle.

If one sets the same `ImageSize`, it's ok as long as one does not play with the `ImagePadding`.

```
Labeled[DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
  ImageSize -> 300, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"], 
 BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {-1, 1}}, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
  ImageSize -> 300, LegendMarkerSize -> 300], {{Top, Center}}]
```

[image]

When creating columns/rows of plots, it is crucial to modify the default `ImagePadding` to fix the size of all plots that I create. **But then I do not know how to fit the size of the `BarLegend` without  trial and error** - the way its margins work is a mystery (`LegendMargins` is not really a great option - I find it very frustrating to work with).

```
Labeled[DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
  ImageSize -> 300, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
  ImagePadding -> {{50, 2}, {2, 2}}], 
 BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {-1, 1}}, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
  ImageSize -> 300, LegendMarkerSize -> 250], {{Top, Center}}]
```

[image]

Would greatly appreciate your advice on how to tackle this issue.
I'm aware that there were [questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50913/control-barlegend-size) about this problem before, but the answers do not really help.

Comment: does it help if you change `{{Top, Center}}` to `{{Top, Right}}` ?

Comment: @kglr it doesn't really help with the size (played with the suggested option, doesn't look good). The problem is that there is no `ImagePadding` for `BarLegend` and the `LegendMargins` option is, imho, not really working well.

Comment: Gregory, could you check if `ipad = {{50, 8}, {2, 2}};
Legended[DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
  ImageSize -> 300, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
  ImagePadding -> ipad, PlotRangeClipping -> False], 
 Placed[BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {-1, 1}}, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
   Method -> {ImageSize -> 300, 
     ImagePadding -> {{0, 0}, {20, 0}} + ipad}], {Above, Right}]]` works in your version/os. It works in version 9 / windows 10.

Comment: `DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, ImageSize -> 300, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", ImagePadding -> ipad, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {-1, 1}}, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
    Method -> {ImageSize -> 300, 
      ImagePadding -> ipad + {{0, 0}, {0, 20}}}], {Above, Right}]]` also works in v9/w10.

Comment: @kglr Nope - both of them do not work:-(. Using v11.1.1/w10. It's like Mathematica didn't actually see `ImagePadding` inside the  `Method` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a workaround that might help others in the future: do not use  `BarLegend` and create your own bar using `DensityPlot`. This way one gets the `ImagePadding` option.

Here's an example that works perfectly.

**Horizontal bar legend**

```
myBarPlot = 
 DensityPlot[x, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
  AspectRatio -> 1/15, FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {True, None}}, 
  ImagePadding -> {{50, 8}, {20, 2}}, ImageSize -> 300];

Column[{myBarPlot, 
  DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, ImageSize -> 300, 
   ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
   ImagePadding -> {{50, 8}, {2, 2}}]}, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]

**Vertical bar legend**
Second case, suggested by @OkkesDulgerci

```
myBarPlotVertical = 
 DensityPlot[y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
  AspectRatio -> 15, FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
  ImagePadding -> {{2, 25}, {5, 5}}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}];

Row[{DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
   ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
   ImagePadding -> {{50, 8}, {5, 5}}, PlotRangePadding -> None], 
  myBarPlotVertical}]
```

[image]

Still, would be great to know, if there's an "official" way to do it using `BarLegend`.

Comment: Additionally, one can use `PlotRangePadding -> None` in the plot to lose the white areas by the frame ticks.

Comment: Here is the vertical barlegend `DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, AspectRatio -> 15, 
 ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
 ImagePadding -> {{1, 15}, {8, 8}}, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 ImageSize -> 30]`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci good point, added this case as well.

Answer (score 2):

You gave a good answer. However, in addition to that, here is the one based on using the standard technique:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, ImageSize -> 300, 
 ImagePadding -> {{50, 2}, {2, 2}}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[Row[{Spacer[30], 
     BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {-1, 1}}, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
      LegendMarkerSize -> 300 - 26]}], {Above, Center}]]
```

[image]

One can play with two parameters to adjust the size and position: (1) the argument of the Spacer as well as with (2) the value of the LegendMarkerSize.

Have fun!

Comment: This `Spacer` is a nice thing, didn't know about it! Feels like a workaround as well though (since, a you said, one has to play with 2 parameters - there's no systematic way of dealing with the legend). I think that the problem lies in the margins of the `BarLegend` - they are i) unknown, ii) uneven.